# Is it possible to squash and rename git commits on remote repository without `push --force`?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I need to squash and rename some commits in remote repository history. I can do it on my branch with `git rebase -i` but trying to push it using `git push --force` gives me errors. It says:

```
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master
```

So is there a way around this or do I need to have setting on the remote repository modified to allow this?

Comment: No, because the history will be incompatible. You'll need to push force or push to a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid the non-fast forward push is to first delete the remote branch and then push it again.

```
git push origin :master
git push origin master
```

Note that you may need to set `receive.denyDeleteCurrent` to `ignore` or `warn` to allow deleting the branch.